# Search several tables with the same structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with several tables that have the same structure. I would want to search all these tables in the sam query. How do I do that?

Like this (dummy code):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(some_column), some_common_column 
FROM table1, table2, tabl3
```

Is there a way to just slam them all together in a query and treat them as one? Merging them is not an option.

Comment: Do a UNION ALL (before GROUP BY.) But why do you have several tables with the same structure?

Comment: if your tables have same structure, it's better to use one table with a `type` field and then you run you query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UNION:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(some_column), some_common_column FROM
    (SELECT some_column, some_common_column FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT some_column, some_common_column FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT some_column, some_common_column FROM table3)
GROUP BY some_common_column;
```

Comment: You might want to include a link to mysql documentation about union:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Yes, UNION ALL is correct, as the sum is what's needed, not the actual matches (otherwise, it would produce duplicates if the same data was present in several tables). Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score -1):

No you can never do that with out a join.